# Multi step ahead prediction using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to predict 7 days ahead of BOD(Biochemical oxygen demand) of surface water. My sample size is just 18. I am using `narnet` in MATLAB for the work.

Here is the sample input:

```
(0.9000  0.4774  0.8849  0.1000  0.6797  0.1000  0.9000  0.2721  0.1444
 0.1978  0.5444  0.4111  0.9000  0.1755  0.3566  0.3868  0.6585  0.8094)
```

And here is the code:

**Input:**

```
clc,clear;
plt=0;
T=load('BOD test.txt');
L=length(T);
net=narnet(1:.1,10);
view(net),
[Xs,Xsi,Asi,Ts] = preparets( net, {}, {}, T );
ts = cell2mat(Ts);
plt = plt+1; figure(plt), hold on
plot( 1:L, ts, 'LineWidth', 2 )
rng( 'default' )
[net, tr, Ys, Es, Af, Xf] = train( net, Xs, Ts, Xsi, Asi );
view( net )
NMSEs = mse( Es ) /var( ts,1 ) 
ys = cell2mat( Ys );
plot( 1:L, ys, 'ro', 'LineWidth', 2 )
axis( [ 0 22 0 1.3 ] )
legend( 'TARGET', 'OUTPUT' )
title( 'OPENLOOP NARNET RESULTS')
 [ netc Xci Aci ] = closeloop(net,Xsi,Asi);
 view(netc)
 [Xc,Xci,Aci,Tc] = preparets(netc,{},{},T);
 [ Yc Xcf Acf ] = netc(Xc,Xci,Aci);
 Ec = gsubtract(Tc,Yc);
 yc = cell2mat(Yc);
 tc = ts;
 NMSEc = mse(Ec) /var(tc,1)
```

**Output**

```
NMSEs =

    1.0000

Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Error in gsubtract>calc_general (line 40)
    c = bsxfun(@minus,a,b);

Error in gsubtract>calc_cell (line 60)
  for i=1:numel(a), c{i} = calc_general(a{i},b); end

Error in gsubtract (line 24)
  c = calc_cell(a,b);
```

Why the value of NMSE is showing 1? Here is the curve plot of 'Openloop narnet results'
:
[Openloop narnet results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12lwY.png)

What's the problem with the input and output? I am new in MATLAB. So cordial help is necessary.